# How work jQuery ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have object:

```
function myObj (){
  this.name = "noName";
}

myObj.prototype = {
  init: function(){
    console.log(this);
    this.setName();
  },
  setName: function(){
    this.name = "object name";
  }
}
```

> var obj = new myObj();

and after I call:

> jQuery(obj.init)

**console.log(this)** from **init** give ***#document***

but if I call it manual from chrome console

> obj.init();

it give me ***myObj { ... }***

can someone explain me wtf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing specific to `ready` here. This is all about how `this` works.

`jQuery(obj.init)` passes the **value** of `obj.init`, so when the function gets called it doesn't get called in the context of `obj` so `this` is different.

Use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) if you want to create a wrapper function that provides a specific context.

```
jQuery(obj.init.bind(obj));
```